Pytorch- Is it possible to apply self-attention into Faster R-CNN's ROI layer?
Everyone; I am trying to apply Self-attention mechanism in Faster R-CNN's ROI layers output. My task is to have Action Recognition; I have used different architectures from vanilla CNN + GRU to Pretrained Resnet + LSTM.
Before applying to it. I am trying to access the ROI layer to apply self attention. However, I am now questioning myself that Is it possible to apply self attention into ROI that ask for targets and bboxes. I don't necessarily need to have ground truth, but the main idea is to take the pre-trained Faster R-CNN and freeze the weights so that there would be no backpropagation. I am having a problem problem as AssertionError: targets should not be none when in training mode
I am setting models to training models. Then, access the model and freeze its weight. But it is not working as I expected. I commented on some parts of the code before applying the rest.  I would be really grateful if someone help me to figure out the problem whether it is technical or practical.
class FasterRCNNGRU(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_classes,checkpoint_file  = None):
        super(FasterRCNNGRU, self).__init__()
        self.num_classes = num_classes

        if checkpoint_file is not None:
            state_dict = torch.load(checkpoint_file)
            print('FasterRCNN loading from checkpoint !')
        else:
            state_dict = fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn(pretrained=True).state_dict()
            print('FasterRCNN loading from scratch !')
        
        self.base_model = fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn()
        self.base_model.load_state_dict(state_dict)
        self.base_model.roi_heads.box_predictor = nn.Identity()
        
        # Set the model to evaluation mode
        #self.base_model.eval()

        # Freeze the weights of the base model
        for param in self.base_model.parameters():
            param.requires_grad = False

        
        self.attention = SelfAttention(2048)

        self.gru = nn.GRU(2048,512,num_layers=5,batch_first=True,dropout=0.5)
        self.bn0 = nn.BatchNorm1d(512)
        self.fc0 = nn.Linear(512,num_classes)
        

    def forward(self,x):
        batch_size, timesteps, C, H, W = x.size()
        x = x.view(batch_size * timesteps, C, H, W)

        # Pass the input through the base model
        features = self.base_model(x)


        # Reshape the features
        '''
        features = features.view(batch_size, timesteps, -1)

        attn_output = self.attention(features)
        gru_output, _ = self.gru(attn_output)
        gru_output = gru_output[:, -1, :]

        output = self.bn0(gru_output)
        output = self.fc0(output)
        
        '''

        return features



def main():

    input = torch.randn(2, 16, 3, 224, 224).to(device)

    checkpoint_file = 'checkpoints/fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn_coco-258fb6c6.pth'
    model = FasterRCNNGRU(10)
    print(model)

    model.to(device)
    #model.train()
    output = model(input)

